# Getting values from multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have this checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" class="calc" name="access[a]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="calc" name="access[b]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="calc" name="access[c]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="calc" name="access[d]" value="4" />
```

I need the following thing, i will explain it in an example:
Let's say i  have selected the first and the second checkbox then "ab"([access[a]+access[b]) and "3"(1+2) will be send.

EDIT1:
You did not undertsand me.I want **2** things to be send, calculation of value and access[values].

Example:
User selects third and fourth fields, 7(3+4) and cd ([access[c]+access[d]) will be send.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another vanilla solution:

```
var res = [ ].reduce.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'input.calc:checked' ), function( a, b ) {
    return a + (+b.value || 0);
}, 0);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fsbTS/

Comment: Nice. `var $ = function(sel){ return Array.prototype.slice.call(0,document.querySelectorAll(sel)); }` and `function sum(a,b){ return a+b}` which'd let you do (without a 80kb library!) do `var res = $("input.calc:checked").,map(getValue).reduce(sum)` something like http://jsfiddle.net/x6374/

Comment: Everybody seems to misunderstood my question. I updated my question, would you mind checking it out ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through it

```
var added= 0;
$(".calc:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
    added += +$(this).val();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/8yz9r/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory vanilla answer:

Grab the elements in an array by class (you can also use `querySelectorAll(".calc")` (or `[name*='access']` etc)

Loop the array of elements, check for the checked property, and add to the sum (making sure to parse the value as an Int to avoid `NaN` issues)

```
var sum = 0;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("calc");
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].checked) sum+= parseInt(x[i].value,10); //parse as int
}
```